# What constitutes asynchronous-safeness

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, synchronization, signal-handling

It is said that you should only call **asynchronous-safe** functions inside a signal handler. My question is, what constitutes **asynchronous-safeness**? A function which is both *reentrant* and *thread safe* is **asynchronous-safe** I guess? Or No?

Comment: Found [this](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/BB.+Definitions). So it seems that function may not use global variables (beside atomic types) and interrupting it at any point should leave the process in consistent state.

Comment: I'd say reentrant and not accessing thread local stuff. If you access thread local stuff you'll be competing with the thread you'll be interrupting and possibly cause data corruption.

Answer (score 14):

Re-entrance and thread safety has a little or nothing to do with this. Side effects, state and interruption of those functions are facts that matter.

> [asynchronous-safe function](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/BB.+Definitions) [GNU Pth]
>
> A function is asynchronous-safe,
>   or asynchronous-signal safe, if it can be called safely and without
>   side effects from within a signal handler context. That is, it must be
>   able to be interrupted at any point to run linearly out of sequence
>   without causing an inconsistent state. It must also function properly
>   when global data might itself be in an inconsistent state. Some
>   asynchronous-safe operations are listed here:
>
> - call the `signal()` function to reinstall a signal handler
> - unconditionally modify a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable (as
>     modification to this type is atomic)
> - call the `_Exit()` function to
>     immediately terminate program execution
> - invoke an asynchronous-safe
>     function, as specified by your implementation
>
> Few functions are
>   portably asynchronous-safe. If a function performs any other
>   operations, it is probably not portably asynchronous-safe.

A rule of thumb is this - only signal some condition variable from signal handler (such as futex/pthread condition, wake up epoll loop etc.).

**UPDATE:**

As EmployedRussian suggested, even calling `pthread_cond_signal` is a bad idea. I've checked the source code of the recent `eglibc` and it has lock/unlock pair in there. Thus, introducing a possibility for a deadlock. This leaves us with few options to signal other threads:

1. Using [`eventfd`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/eventfd.2.html).
2. Changing global atomic variable and hope that SA_RESTART is not set and other threads will check our atomic.

Comment: There is a much larger list of functions that are [guaranteed to be async-signal-safe by POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) (you'll have to scroll down a bit for the list), including the majority of traditional-Unix "system calls," and access to `errno`.  Also, if you know that your signal handlers will only be called when normal execution is blocked on [`sigsuspend`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsuspend.html), then it's safe to do arbitrary stuff in the handler.

Comment: None of `pthread_*` functions are async-signal-safe, so "signal pthread condition variable" is a bad advice (TM).

Comment: @EmployedRussian: Not that it is not safe, it might just not wake up someone waiting on a POSIX condition variable.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: Actually, I take my words back - just checked the source code and it may as well lead to deadlock :-) So I guess the only safe wakeup is trough fcntl and/or atomic variable.

Comment: The usual trick for waking up a `select`-style main loop from a signal handler is to write a byte to a pipe that is in the fds-of-interest set.  [`signalfd`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signalfd) may also be of interest.

Comment: `sem_post()` is async-signal-safe, making it perfect for signaling a thread waiting in `sem_wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

For your own code, yes, re-entrant and thread-safe are the characteristics you need, as, depending on how you set up your signal handling mechanism, your signal handler may itself be interrupted by another signal. In general, try to do as little work as possible inside the signal handler. Setting flags to trigger special code in your normal program flow is probably all you should be doing.

For functions in the OS that you might call, check out `man 7 signal` for a list of what is safe to call. Note that `malloc()` and `free()` are **not** on the list. The pthread synchronization APIs are not on the list either, but I would think that some would have to be safe to call, so you can set a global flag safely in a signal handler.